# How to do "inline solution" <input type="text"> to only allow number and if else it will also give an alert too?

Tags: javascript, html, input, alert, inline

How do I do a **inline solution** using the same solution as under but with an alert message added. Right now it does not allow text and only allows number as it should but there is no alert. I need to add an alert message if not a number is inserted without modifying too much the function as it is now. How do I add that alert to it?

**Remember** because of technical issues on my page I search for a **short simple inline solution** not some query or separate JavaScript unless there is no other way then a separate JavaScript.

**HTML with inline JavaScript:**

```
<input type="text" name="areinp" size="30" value="" onChange="areCon()" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^\d]/,'');">
```

**UPDATE:** I changed it to `type="number"` but the problem of the alert message stays the same. I need an alert message in case somebody is typing a alphabet instead of a number.

```
<input type="number" name="areinp" size="30" value="" onChange="areCon()">
```

Comment: `<input type="number" ..>` ?

Comment: okay number works and now I modified it as you told me. Thank you. But the problem is still not solved. How do I get the alert message to it if a text that is not a number is imputed so that the user knows why the text does not come up.

Comment: Did you try it? (https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_number  -- try inputting not-a number and submit)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<input>` tag specifies an input field where the user can enter data.
`<input type="text">` defines a one-line text input field:

```
<form>
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname">
</form>
```

Reference: [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp).

In your case, you used `<input type="text">`.

For this condition you can use type number, and user only can type numbers inside.

```
<input type="number">
```

For show one alert to user, try use one function:

HTML:

```
<form name="myForm" action="" onsubmit="return checkInp()" method="post">
    Number: <input type="text" name="number">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Javascript:

```
function checkInp()
{
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["number"].value;
    var regex = /^[0-9]+$/;
    if (!x.match(regex))
    {
        alert("Must input numbers");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Add in your tag html: `onsubmit="return checkInp()"`
Or you can use what @Andrii answer, `<input type="submit">` and only numbers will send.

Obs.: I'm not sure if it is the best practicies for did this... But, this is what you want and With my edition, you will be able to make the user type any caracther, but if the user sends text, it will display an alert with the message "Must enter numbers

Comment: I did use `number` in my update, the problem is that I need an alert message too at the same time. It is the alert message problem that is not solved.

Comment: With my edition, you will be able to make the user type any caracther, but if the user sends text, it will display an alert with the message "Must enter numbers"

Comment: I wish it was an inline solution so I would minimize the text amount to not make it too much as my file already has too much, but if there is no inline solution, then the JavaScript tagged solution you gave me is worth using too.

Comment: I tested your solution now. Sadly it does not work on `onkeyup`. It works only for `onsubmit` and that is a problem for me as this function I use now has no submit, but it is automatic at onkeyup.

Comment: just modify to onkeyup :)

Comment: This is what I did `<input type="text" name="areinp" id="areinp" size="30" value="" onChange="areCon()" onkeyup="return checkInp()">` and I used exactly your JavaScript like this
`<script language="JavaScript">
function checkInp()
{
    var x = document.forms["areinp"].value;
    var regex = /^[0-9]+$/;
    if (!x.match(regex))
    {
        alert("Must input numbers");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>`
And not did not work

Comment: Here works fine, I just modify to onkeyup and everytime if I type some text, the alert is open to me in my browser.

Comment: Well I gave you a copy of my code above on the comment. Maybe you can figure out why it did not work for me. As you see I changed `["myForm"]["number"]` to `["areinp"]` and I used `onkeyup="return checkInp()"` and it did not work.

Comment: Okay now it works. I know what mistake I did now. I linked directly to the input but forgot to link it to the form too. Brb... It works now.

Comment: There is still one more problem, but I know how to solve that on my own. The problem that now it leaves behind a text, but if I use that JavaScript I made it will not. So yea this last part I know the solution on my own.
THANK YOU for helping me on this part.

Comment: If you have more problems, just ask, and if I can help you, I'll :)

Comment: Thank you. The problem is that if I use `type="text"` and not `type="number"` and if the person typing is a fast tipper like me, he will type 2 or 3 characters tills the alert comes and then the alert even with my code of `this.value=this.value.replace(/[^\d]/,'')` it will only delete one alphabet and if I do not use my code it will delete no alphabet at all.
So I will end up with an alert as I want to, but with two or 3 alphabet characters in the box that should not be there.

Comment: you can test use one if condition for this? And the alert will show only if user type some text in the input. It's a good idea ask a new question, because mayme my knowledge isn't the best practicies, I dont know, I'll try help you anyway. Paste the link of your new question here please :)

Comment: Okay will do so. Here: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43401238/how-do-i-get-an-input-alert-message-to-work-only-when-imputing-alphabets-not-fo[/ link]
The question continues with a new question that maybe I find a solution to repair this.

Comment: Just an WARNING to you. NEVER try to do this with your code `<script language="JavaScript">
function checkInp(){
  var count = 0;
  // delay in milliseconds
  var delay = 1;

  var interval = setInterval(function(){
    if (count++ < 100) {
        delaycheckInp();
      } else {
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
  }, delay);
}

function delaycheckInp()
{
    var x = document.forms["isnform04"]["areinp"].value;
    var regex = /^[0-9]+$/;
    if (!x.match(regex))
    {
        alert("no text here, input numbers only");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>`

Comment: Because I tried that above in the comment. And it forced me to force close my browser because it would not shut down. It was like a virus, it just came and came up with alerts without being able to close it and shut down the browser.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [HTML  pattern Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp):

```html
<form onsubmit="return false;">
    Number <input type="text" pattern="[\d]+" title="Please enter a number">
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: For some reason, I do not know why, your solution refuses to work on my chrome browser.

Comment: I have checked and it works only when input is inside form tag. Make sure that your input is also inside the form. If you don't want the from then this approach won't work.

Comment: @SeekLoad, I have updated form tag so that it won't post anything if that's not needed. So you could still use it.

Comment: I did it like this `<input type="text" name="areinp" size="30" value="" onChange="areCon()" style="text-align:center; border:1;"  pattern="[\d]+" title="Please enter a number">` but nothing. I do have form tags and a loot of JavaScript, that is why I search for an inline solution so I do not add to much text and make it too heavy and sluggish.

Comment: If I chose a JavaScrpit tagged solution then it would work for sure, but the price would be a more heavier system. Well if I find no perfectly working and all browser reliable inline solution, I probably will have to go for a JavaScript tagged solution instead.

Comment: Well, my solution works in all modern browsers http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-pattern. I cannot tell what prevents it to work in your chrome. Does my code snipped works in your chrome?

Comment: Probably. Look I will now close this question as I already got the answer for half of the question and that was about how to get with a simple solution to work only with numbers. The other half I will now add another question of how to get the alert work with an inline solution when alphabet and not numbers is pushed.
I thought I could get two question answered into one. Sadly I only got one question answered.

Comment: Sure, no worries.

Answer (score 1):

One thing is **declare an input of specific type**. Then just accept to write a value of this type.
For instance when you declare:

```
<input type="number"/>
```

But validation means other. Validation refers to a validation function. And JS give us tools to implement them.

**Validation function doesn't take care of what type is your input**. It take the value of a DOM element, for example a text-box. 
It decide if it's valid or not, for the case you have specified. 
Then acts as you desire for the value and for the DOM elements in the cases of valid or invalid.

**You can easily add a script code in your HTML and integrate a validation.**

This example shows how is **the right way** to implement a validation using JS. You will find some functions for validate email, name or when the value is a number (what you requested).

For dynamic validation while the user is filling the form it calls specific validation functions 'onblur' what means 'on focus lost'. You will find it on expressions:

```
onblur="validateFunction(value)"
```

When the user submits he is calling to the form validation function. Which is supported by individual validation functions. Doing a last-check for all the values. For example you could implement here if you want to have some required fields. Better than avoid void values per each individual validation. In this way we have got right encapsulation for functions. We get this when define:

```
<form action="" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
```

and then:

```
<fieldset>
  <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</fieldset>
```

Give a look and feel free to ask what you need.

```html
  <script>
    function validateName(x){
      // Validation rule
      var re = /[A-Za-z -']$/;
      // Check input
      if(re.test(document.getElementById(x).value)){
        // Style green
        document.getElementById(x).style.background ='#ccffcc';
        // Hide error prompt
        document.getElementById(x + 'Error').style.display = "none";
        return true;
      }else{
        // Style red
        document.getElementById(x).style.background ='#e35152';
        // Show error prompt
        document.getElementById(x + 'Error').style.display = "block";
        return false; 
      }
    }
    // Validate email
    function validateEmail(email){ 
      var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
      if(re.test(email)){
        document.getElementById('email').style.background ='#ccffcc';
        document.getElementById('emailError').style.display = "none";
        return true;
      }else{
        document.getElementById('email').style.background ='#e35152';
        return false;
      }
    }
    //Validate number
    function validateNumber(num) {
    if (!isNaN(parseFloat(num)) && isFinite(num)) {
      //is number
        document.getElementById('numberError').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('number').style.background ='#ccffcc';
    } else {
      //no number
       document.getElementById('number').style.background ='#e35152';
    }
    }
 
    function validateForm(){
      // Set error catcher
      var error = 0;
      // Check name
      if(!validateName('name')){
        document.getElementById('nameError').style.display = "block";
        error++;
      }
      // Validate email
      if(!validateEmail(document.getElementById('email').value)){
        document.getElementById('emailError').style.display = "block";
        error++;
      }
      //Validate number
      if(!validateNumber(document.getElementById('number').value)){
        document.getElementById('numberError').style.display = "block";
        error++;
      }
      
      // Don't submit form if there are errors
      if(error > 0){
        return false;
      }
    }     
  </script>
 
 <form action="" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
    <fieldset>
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" onblur="validateName(name)" />
      <span id="nameError" style="display: none;">You can only use alphabetic characters, hyphens and apostrophes</span>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <label for="email">Email</label>
      <input type="text" name="email" id="email" onblur="validateEmail(value)" />
      <span id="emailError" style="display: none;">You must enter a valid email address</span>
    </fieldset> 
    <fieldset>
      <label for="number">Number</label>
      <input type="text" name="number" id="number" onblur="validateNumber(value)" />
      <span id="numberError" style="display: none;">You must enter a number</span>
    </fieldset> 
      
    <fieldset>
      <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </fieldset>   
  </form>
```