# How do I get an input alert message to work only when imputing alphabets, not for numbers? Without letting any text tipped in

Tags: javascript, html, input, alert, inline

How do I get an input alert message to work only when imputing alphabets, not for numbers? Without letting any text tipped in.
When imputing numbers there should be no alerts, but when imputing alphabets you get an alert. I accept a JavaScript tagged solution too, but if there is an **inline solution** then that is preferred.

The problem with this function is that it lets the text you type in the box if you are fast tipper as I am. It should be **without letting any text tipped in**.

**JavaScript:**

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function checkInp()
{
    var x = document.forms["isnform04"]["areinp"].value;
    var regex = /^[0-9]+$/;
    if (!x.match(regex))
    {
        alert("no text here, input numbers only");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" name="areinp" size="30" value="" onChange="areCon()" onkeyup="return checkInp();">
```

**No query solution plz.**

**UPDATE:** I also used this one:

```
<input type="text" name="areinp" size="30" value="" onChange="areCon()" onkeyup="if (this.value=this.value.replace(/[^\d]/,'')) alert('no text here, input numbers only');">
```

Comment: please add, what you have tried.

Comment: What is an "input alert" and "text tipped in"? Also, inline JavaScript is a very bad practice and is widely discouraged.

Comment: Why not use `type="number"`?

Comment: @ScottMarcus I mean an alert in the input text box. Also text tipped in means without letting text left in the text box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `preventDefault()` if you want to to cancel the event, that is to disallow text box from accepting non-numeric input. So that you don't have to bother about deleting it. However, `preventDefault()` does not work with `onkeyup`. Use `onkeydown`.

**JS**:

```
function checkKey(e) 
{
    if (e.keyCode != 8 && // allow backspace
        e.keyCode != 46 && // allow delete
        e.keyCode != 37 && // allow left arrow
        e.keyCode != 39 && // allow right arrow
        (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) // allow numerics only
    {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<input type="text" onkeydown="checkKey(event)" />
```

Note - Alerting user on each key press / down / up is terrible. Simply annoying. Avoid! Silently block the unwanted keys as I showed above.

Comment: Your solution also worked as well as mine, so thank you, b coincidence we came up with a solution at the same time. That is why I am giving you 1 vote up and also question answered accept.

Comment: For yours to work exactly as I want to I added `alert("Do not input text here, input numbers only.");` after `e.preventDefault()`. Like this `e.preventDefault() alert("Do not input text here, input numbers only.");` and it works PERFECT and it is a loot shorter then my solution.... THANK YOU....

Comment: I still feel showing alert on every key stroke is a bad user experience. `Alert` would look better if you were validating `onblur` of text box or `onclick` of submit button because It would be displayed only once. You can simply use `placeholder = "enter numerics only"` attribute on text box from HTML5.

Comment: SeekLoad: if you alert on every keystroke your users will absolutely check the 'prevent this site showing alerts' option, which means you deliberately engineer your own failure of notification. Either use the console, or an element, the input element, to provide feedback. (Reposted to notify the right person, my apologies to Nikhil.)

Comment: So you mean not use an alert, just type information on the page saying "only numbers plz" and then use the java to not allow anything else?

Comment: @SeekLoad Yes. That will attract users than irritate. But of course, all this, only if your requirements are flexible.

Answer (score 1):

Put a regular expression test in the `onkeyup` attribute.

```
onkeyup="if(/\D/.test(this.value)) alert('no text here, input numbers only')"
```

Comment: Problem and that is that is that I get the alert, but it does not delete the text I typed.

Comment: Return false to prevent it from updating

Answer (score 0):

By playing around and mixing with different codes I found the answer on my own. I made a filter who lets only the characters chosen by me in the box and then added a alert message to it and WHALA there it works.

This is the answer I found:

**JavaScript:**

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function TextFilter(myfield, e)
{
    var key;
    var keychar;
    if (window.event)
    key = window.event.keyCode;
    else if (e)
    key = e.which;
    else
    return true;
    keychar = String.fromCharCode(key);

    if ((key==null) || (key==0) || (key==8) || (key==9) || (key==13) || (key==27) )
    return true;

    else if ((("0123456789.").indexOf(keychar) > -1))
    return true;

    else if ((keychar == ""))
    {
        if (myfield.value.indexOf(keychar) > -1)
        return false;
    }
    else
    return false;
}

function checkInp()
{
    var x = document.forms["isnform04"]["areinp"].value;
    var regex = /^[0-9]+$/;
    if (!x.match(regex))
    {
        alert("no text here, input numbers only");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" name="areinp" id="test" size="30" value="" onChange="areCon()" onkeypress="return TextFilter(this, event)" onkeyup="checkInp()">
```